# Response code strings from JSON API

Tags: authorize.net

We've updated an old Authnet API to the JSON interface but need a formal list of response code strings it can return (approved/denied/etc) from a charge transaction.  Is there documentation anywhere that covers this?

Thanks!

--Ben

Comment: please provide more info

Comment: I don't really get what you are talking about; [Is this it ?](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)

Comment: Sorry, will try this again...  When I submit a charge to Authnet via a JSON connection, it returns a response code and response string.  In sandbox mode I can see what text it returns if I enter a bad credit card #, but want to know what the list of possible return codes and strings there are.  I would think that would have been part of their documentation, but can't find anything on their site about it.    Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You question is to broad to provide all of the answers, so here are some examples:

```
    {

    "code" : "I00001",

    "text" : "Successful.",

    "description" : "The request was processed successfully.",

    "integration_suggestions": "",

    "other_suggestions": ""

},

{

    "code" : "I00002",

    "text" : "The subscription has already been canceled.",

    "description" : "The subscription has already been canceled.",

    "integration_suggestions": "",

    "other_suggestions": ""

},

{

    "code" : "I00003",

    "text" : "The record has already been deleted.",

    "description" : "The record has already been deleted.",

    "integration_suggestions": "",

    "other_suggestions": ""

},

{

    "code" : "I00004",

    "text" : "No records found.",

    "description" : "No records have been found that match your query.",

    "integration_suggestions": "",

    "other_suggestions": ""

},

{

    "code" : "I00005",

    "text" : "The mobile device has been submitted for approval by the account administrator.",

    "description" : "The mobile device was successfully inserted into the database.",

    "integration_suggestions": "",

    "other_suggestions": ""

},

{

    "code" : "I00006",

    "text" : "The mobile device is approved and ready for use.",

    "description" : "The mobile device was successfully registered and approved by the account administrator.",

    "integration_suggestions": "",

    "other_suggestions": ""

}
```

To see the full list please visit their api reference documentation which is currently located [here](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/dist/json/responseCodes.json).

Comment: Answer has been updated based on suggestions in feedback.

Comment: Taking another look on the question shows, that this question is defineately off topic. Your initial answer therefore was really a good answer for that question, but was still off topic, since the question is asked in a way that does not apply to the community rules. So good job from your side :-) You will get a better feeling for questions that are worth answering, once you spend more time here. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Hi Philipp, was the question I asked off topic?  Where should I have asked it?  Jay answered what I was looking for perfectly.  Thanks much!

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: The check mark on the left of the answer under the up/down vote arrows.